Can I specify to generate full chain in OpenSSL cert request config?
Can I specify in the certificate request config file that I would like to have the CA generate the whole cert chain instead just the head cert. This would allow me to skip the step of generating the upstream cert myself.
(Background: A customer requires to have the whole chain deployed on our site otherwise their firewall blocks the requests.)
Here is my open ssl config file for clarity:
[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha256
prompt             = no
encrypt_key        = no

# distinguished name
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

# attributes
req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C  = GB
ST = Somewhere
L  = Somewhere
O  = Company
OU = Company ltd
CN = *.company.com

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = *.test.company.com
DNS.2 = *.company.com

Thanks for the help even if it cannot be done for sure :)
